# Cannot flash errors array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I am having trouble flashing my errors array.  Currently I am calling `notice: errors`, but that is returning an array that looks like this

["Please enter score range one.", "Please enter score range two.", "Please enter range between 1 and 100 for score one.", "Please enter range between 1 and 100 for score two."]

If I call `flash: errors` than I get this error

`undefined method 'keys' for #<Array:0x0000010f196198>`

What would be a better way of doing this?  My code is below

```
if beg_score.present? && end_score.present? && beg_score.to_i.between?(1, 100) && end_score.to_i.between?(1, 100)
  CallLogByScoreWorker.perform_async(beg_score, end_score, query)
  redirect_to call_logs_path, notice: 'Calls were successfully made.'
else
  errors = []
  unless beg_score.present?
    errors << 'Please enter score range one.'
  end
  unless end_score.present?
    errors << 'Please enter score range two.'
  end
  unless beg_score.to_i.between?(1, 100)
    errors << 'Please enter range between 1 and 100 for score one.'
  end
  unless end_score.to_i.between?(1, 100)
    errors << 'Please enter range between 1 and 100 for score two.'
  end
redirect_to call_logs_path, flash: errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
redirect_to call_logs_path, flash: errors
```

do:

```
redirect_to call_logs_path, notice: errors.join(' ')
```

This way, it will return a string like the following:

```
'Please enter score range one. Please enter score range two. Please enter range between 1 and 100 for score one. Please enter range between 1 and 100 for score two.'
```

Check the RubyDocs documentation on the [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) method.